# Simple transistor switching circuit

Tags: led, transistors, 7segmentdisplay

What should I do to the circuit:

[image: circuit] so that the LED is lit. 
Multisim [file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Anq2KXMNfyPrxWQoi9xDzVpTfmK1)

I know Q1 does not have ground nor is the VCC connected to the Q2. The above is part of this commercially sold driver board

[image: entirecircuit]

Note that VCC and Common Ground are controlled by a jumper that is set to Ck. And because of this there is no ground to the first transistor's emitter. The 3V is the 'p' in the second image which is fed from microcontroller. I tried removing the bias voltage (3V), connecting to the ground (changing the jumper).
I would like to point out that in practice, i am using Vcc as a 9V battery that I have on common ground with the 5V from microcontroller.

Note: This is a follow-up on this question that I asked in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/7b73lv/what_am_i_doing_wrong_7_segment_display_connection/) with no response.

As I was not getting any response, I figured out if i dumb down the circuit to easier level, I might get better response. Please help. I am seriously going nuts!

EDIT 1: I found the manuals of the [7 segment display](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/makeweb/EeZNluzYD/Document/MX003_1_A3.pdf) and [driver](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/makeweb/EeZNluzYD/Document/MX007_1_A3.pdf). Can some one tell me why a common cathode is connected to +ve.

EDIT 2: Based on @jonk comment, I am trying to get it working in Common Anode. The schematic I redrew in Circuit Lab reflecting the jumper changes. I am still not able to figure out how the circuit fully orchestrates and its working. If i connect the Q2 to VCC then when I simulate a DC sweep I am getting a jump from 8V to 12V after Vbe > 0.7. Not understanding why it was not in the cutoff region before.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS1k9y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If you look at the paper schematic the emitter of Q1 is ultimately connected to a jumper that does not reach ground. Am I flawed in representing this?

Comment: I just spent five minutes reading. It looks to me like the driver called MXA007 (is the MX007 different? or the same?) is designed to ONLY be used in "common anode" mode. Read the sheet where it says ***"Segment use type common anode."*** Sure, all of the web sites say just the exact opposite. And there are jumpers present. But I think the web site folks are just copying each other in "monkey see, monkey do" without a moment's thought. They are just sellers, after all. The schematic will not work for common cathode displays no matter what you do with the jumpers, so far as I can readily tell.

Comment: Set the MX007/MXA007 as "common cathode" or CK is how you ***disable*** this driver, entirely. Meanwhile, the MXA003 display can be wired either way. It doesn't care. It can be common anode or common cathode. You have different jumpers for each segment and probably should set all of them up the same. All this means is that if you use this display with the MX007/MXA007, then you will want to jumper the segments also for "common anode."

Comment: In short I just need connect it as common anode? Set both jumpers as common anode. I will do a sanity check once I reach back and confirm the same Thanks a lot for your time. Stupid sellers and their jumpers!

Comment: I simulated the circuit putting both the jumpers on CA. I am still not able to lit the LED. Could you please walk me through how the circuit works. I will be really grateful to learn from some one with such rich experience. Your answer to how drawings were drawn before CAD really opened up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver board appears to me to only work in common anode mode. The web sites I looked at all say "common cathode" on the page description, which I think is just a mistake made once but duplicated forever after. The pages are just wrong. The manual, however, would appear to have a sentence correct in it but also some misleading information as well as jumpers which would definitely give a wrong impression about the capabilities of the board. I can guess why all this happened, but it would only be guessing.

Working from the schematic you provided, the first thing I have to interpret on the board are the jumper settings shown in the schematic. I interpret the schematic showing where board traces are located. As such, I think the center pin and the upper pin are already connected, with or without the jumper placed on the upper position. An added connection from there only occurs when the jumpers are in place for the "CA" position.

Now let's look at just one segment's circuit, with the jumpers set for CA:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZNSnd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The analysis is pretty simple, if you assume that the collector of \$Q_2\$ is tied to the cathode side of a string of LEDs whose anode end ties to +V. \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ form up a divider yielding 77% of \$\approx V_{CC}\$ and where the Thevenin resistance is \$2.3\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$. The collector of \$Q_1\$ is arranged so that if \$Q_1\$ is ***off***, then \$Q_2\$ experiences about 50% of \$V_{CC}\$ via a Thevenin resistance of \$2.5\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$. But if \$Q_1\$ is ***on***, then \$Q_2\$ is forced ***off***.

The two cases are then:

1. I/O pin applies approximately \$V_{CC}\$ to \$R_1\$, yielding a base current of \$I_B=\frac{0.77\cdot V_{CC}-700\:\textrm{mV}}{2.3\:\textrm{k}\Omega}\$. Given the board's figure of at least \$4.5\:\textrm{V}\$ (I think I saw that somewhere), this suggests \$\approx 1.2\:\textrm{mA}\$ of base current. Since the collector's load is only \$5\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$, the base current is way more than enough to hold \$Q_2\$ ***off*** by holding its base close to ground. So \$Q_2\$'s collector won't sink current and the LED segment is ***off***.
2. I/O pin applies approximately \$0\:\textrm{V}\$ to \$R_1\$, holding \$Q_1\$ ***off***. Now, the pair of \$5\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ resistors form up a divider, supplying a base current into \$Q_2\$ of \$I_B=\frac{0.5\cdot V_{CC}-700\:\textrm{mV}}{2.5\:\textrm{k}\Omega}\$, or \$\ge 1.5\:\textrm{mA}\$ of base current to \$Q_2\$. This should be more than enough for \$Q_2\$'s collector to sink \$20\:\textrm{mA}\$ (\$\beta=15\$.) So the LED segment is ***on***.

None of this works out if the jumpers are set to the CK position, though. I just don't think it works in that mode. This is a "common anode" driver board.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks to your circuit and understanding. The driver works in both CA and CK but irrespective, the 7 segment display has to be in Common Anode.

Comment: @Oasa Interesting about the CA vs CK not mattering. Probably means it is wired up on the board, regardless. Yes, the 7-seg display has to be in common anode format or the driver can't do its job.

Answer (score 3):

> What should I do to the circuit so that the LED is lit

[image]

Ditch it and start over.

This circuit makes no sense at all.  You have a transistor that is either clamping the voltage across the LED or leaving it open.  Neither will light the LED.

You can use a NPN transistor as a switch to either light a LED or not.  The conceptually simple way is to use the transistor in common emitter configuration:

[image]

When the input voltage at the left end of R1 is ground, the transistor is off.  This leaves the bottom end of R2 floating, which prevents current from flowing thru the LED, which keeps it off.

When the input is raised to 5 V, there will be about 1 mA of current into the base.  That will turn on the transistor.  Assuming a typical green LED that drops about 2.1 V, and leaving 200 mV for the C-E drop of the transistor in saturation, that leaves 2.7 V across R2.  By Ohm's law we know that means 18 mA will flow.  That will light the LED nicely, but safely within the 20 mA maximum for a typical LED.

In this case, the transistor is required to have a gain of at least 18.  Just about any small signal NPN transistor can easily be counted on to exceed a gain of 18 at this operating point.

Comment: well in theory it could work by shorting the supply when you want the led off, you just need a really beefy transistor and a supply precisely matched to the forward voltage of the led :P

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I should have written about the [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/7b73lv/what_am_i_doing_wrong_7_segment_display_connection/) question at first. The circuit is actually a small part of a driver circuit that I am using for a 7 segment display. I am breaking my head over it :(

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, in “CK” (common cathode) mode, the circuit is used as shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f71iMA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this mode, Q1 is only used for its B-C diode.

- When IN is driven high, some current flows to Q2’s base and the D1 LED is shorted, which switches it off.
- When IN is driven low, Q2’s base is pulled down by R4, so no current flows to it, and current flows from Vcc through 35 to the D1 LED.

When in “CA” (common anode) mode, Q1 behaves like an inverter.

Comment: You are right as well. The driver does work with the jumper set to CK but irrespective, the LED need to be configured in such a way that it is in CA.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lighting a single LED common anode or cathode is not relevant.

For a battery operated circuit the battery voltage should be just above the LED's forward voltage.

I would use a CCR with an enable pin for the dimming or blinking (e.g. Microchip MIC2860).
A CCR will hold the current constant even as the battery discharges. It is also more efficient than a current limiting resistor.

I'd power it with a Li-ion 3.6V battery.